# Distance Matrix API AsyncTask Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-distancematrix-api

I have been trying to get the walking duration and distance between two locations using Distance Matrix API. I want to store this results (Distance and Duration) in variables that I will be able to access from other classes/activities.

I managed to get time and duration using AsyncTask, but when I try to store them in a variable in PostExecute method, they are always unassigned when accessing from a method or class outside of the PostExecute method. I now, understand how AsyncTask works and that is asynchronous. I tried to implement interfaces and then try to access the data but still I was not able to.

**GeoTask is an inner class in my Map class.**

```
public class GeoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context mContext;

    SelectTime selectTime;



    //constructor is used to get the context.
    public GeoTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    public GeoTask() {
    }

    //This function is executed before before "doInBackground(String...params)" is executed to dispaly the progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        selectTime=new SelectTime();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pd.setMessage("Loading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
    //This function is executed after the execution of "doInBackground(String...params)" to dismiss the dispalyed progress dialog and call "setDouble(Double)" defined in "MainActivity.java"
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aDouble) {
        super.onPostExecute(aDouble);
        if(aDouble!=null)
        {
            setDouble(aDouble);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error4!Please Try Again with proper values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.connect();
            int statuscode=con.getResponseCode();
            if(statuscode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String line=br.readLine();
                while(line!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    line=br.readLine();
                }
                String json=sb.toString();
                Log.d("JSON",json);
                JSONObject root=new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray array_rows=root.getJSONArray("rows");
                Log.d("JSON","array_rows:"+array_rows);
                JSONObject object_rows=array_rows.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("JSON","object_rows:"+object_rows);
                JSONArray array_elements=object_rows.getJSONArray("elements");
                Log.d("JSON","array_elements:"+array_elements);
                JSONObject  object_elements=array_elements.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("JSON","object_elements:"+object_elements);
                JSONObject object_duration=object_elements.getJSONObject("duration");
                JSONObject object_distance=object_elements.getJSONObject("distance");

                Log.d("JSON","object_duration:"+object_duration);
                return object_duration.getString("value")+","+object_distance.getString("value");

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("error", "error1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", "error2");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("error","error3");
        }


        return null;
    }


}
```

In **Map class**, the setDouble method:

```
   public void setDouble(String result) {
    String res[] = result.split(",");
    Double m = Double.parseDouble(res[0]) / 60;
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(res[1])/1000;


    minutes=m
    distance=d


}
```

The minutes and distance variables initialisation

```
private double minutes;

public double getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

private double distance;

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
```

and the execution:

```
 LatLng destinationLatLng = getLatLngFromAddress(destinationPassed);

    currentOrigin = getAddressFromLatLng(currentLat,currentLong);


    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + currentOrigin + "&destinations=" + destinationPassed + "&mode=walking&language=fr-FR&avoid=tolls&key=API_KEY";
    Log.d("url string",url);
    geoTask.execute(url);
```

Furthermore, I try to access the minutes and distance variables using the get methods in another class and I get the value 0.0 returned all the time, even after the PostExecution is completed (I tested that it completed using Logs)

1)How can I achieve what I want? Access the distance and duration returned by the API in different classes? It is essential for the app that I am doing to achieve that.

2)If I cant achieve what I want using AsyncTask and this method, is there any way to use Distance Matrix API without using AsyncTask?

Comment: Did you set your valid API_KEY with enabled [Distance API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=uk) into your `String url = ... avoid=tolls&key=API_KEY";`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should replace in your

`String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + currentOrigin + "&destinations=" + destinationPassed + "&mode=walking&language=fr-FR&avoid=tolls&key=API_KEY";`

line `API_KEY` characters by your valid  [Distance API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=uk) key.

Take a look at [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key) to get information how to obtain valid API key.

Comment: Yeah I know about that, I did that. I just didn't want the whole internet to know my API key so I changed it to "API_KEY" when writing my question on StackOverflow. :D

Comment: @RafaelK Ok. You can put your URL in the browser search bar and analyze the response on your computer. If everything is ok, we move on to find the problem.

Comment: Everything is ok. I managed to solve the problem by storing it in a Textview temporarily and then accessing it on the other class using Intent.getExtra. Thank you for your effort though!

Comment: @RafaelK You did  everything yourself. Good luck!